# Expression Engine: Change status outside admin section

Tags: expressionengine

Is it possible to edit an entrie's status outside the admin section?  I want to be able to open and close entries from the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be some kind of php hook!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, using the {exp:weblog:entry_form} tag and then for example using:

```
<select name="status">
 <option value="open">Open</option>
 <option value="closed">Closed</option>
</select>
```

just using the status name as value^^

Answer (score 0):

This isn't default EE behavior. Seems like you can do inline editing with a little work though.

Here is a detailed how-to on inline editing with EE and Ajax.
http://www.3roadsmedia.com/use-a-modal-box-to-edit-content-inline-with-expressionengine/